# What is the usage of braces in unix commands?

Tags: unix, terminal

I have been looking all over for how to use the {} feature in unix filenames. For example, I have a directory that has subdirectories named as an ID#. Each subdirectory has a recorded audio file named as a specific test question ID#. The following command:

`for file in */1-01*; do echo "$file"; done`

will list the names of the audio files within each subdirectory of the current directory. Doing so gives me a list:

```
809043250/1-01-20131.wav
813777079/1-01-20131.wav
817786199/1-01-20131.wav
827832538/1-01-20131.wav
834820477/1-01-20131.wav
```

I want to rename each of the above .wav files as a different ID#, so it should end up like this:

```
809043250/5001.wav
813777079/5001.wav
817786199/5001.wav
827832538/5001.wav
834820477/5001.wav
```

So how do I use the `${file/firstOccurance/replaceWith}` notation if I want to use the `mv` command to keep the person's ID# (809043250, 813777079, etc) and the first `/` but strip off the `1-01-20131.wav` and tack on `5001.wav` ?

I don't know how to search for this on google. Is it called regular expressions (i don't think so...)? Brace notation? filename patterns? Does anyone know of a good explanation of these?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In `bash`, one variation on the notation is called [Brace Expansion](http://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bash.html#Brace-Expansion).  This generates file names.

The other variation on the notation is called [Shell Parameter Expansion](http://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bash.html#Shell-Parameter-Expansion).  Here, `bash` provides a regex-ish substitute notation `${var/match/replace}`.

For your purposes, you need the paremeter expansion:

```
$ x="809043250/1-01-20131.wav
> 813777079/1-01-20131.wav
> 817786199/1-01-20131.wav
> 827832538/1-01-20131.wav
> 834820477/1-01-20131.wav"
$ for file in $x; do echo $file ${file/1-01-20131/5001}; done
809043250/1-01-20131.wav 809043250/5001.wav
813777079/1-01-20131.wav 813777079/5001.wav
817786199/1-01-20131.wav 817786199/5001.wav
827832538/1-01-20131.wav 827832538/5001.wav
834820477/1-01-20131.wav 834820477/5001.wav
$
```

Comment: THANK YOU!!! If google is a map, not knowing the key to search for is very frustrating! Luckily humans can translate incorrect keys to correct ones and return the values!